# Include used 3rd party libraries in Android Library

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-library

I made an `Android Library`. I upload it to Azure Artifact and pull it to my project from there.

I am making a service call with retrofit in the library. I'm using **Moshi** or **Kotlinx-Serialization** for Converter, but if I don't add these libraries to the Project where I use the library, I get errors like `ClassNotFoundException`. After adding, these errors go away, but the variables in the service models do not hold the data and remain null.

I think this is due to the 3rd party library (Moshi, KotlinX-Serialization, ...).

I found a way to include the 3rd party libraries I use in the library in the .aar package.

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}
```

But when I run the task I got this error.

```
Resolving dependency configuration 'implementation' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'.
Instead, a resolvable ('canBeResolved=true') dependency configuration that extends 'implementation' should be resolved.
```

The .aar file path for my library consists of ->

```
Projects/MySDK-Android/MySDK/build/outputs/aar/MySDK-release.aar
```

I think if I include the 3rd party library I use for serialization (Moshi, KotlinX-Serilalization, Gson, ...) into my library, the problem will be solved.

Any help on how I can do it?

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id "kotlinx-serialization"
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    kotlin {
        // for strict mode
        explicitApi()

        // for warning mode
        explicitApiWarning()
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0"

    // Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1"

    // Logger
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:logger:2.2.0'

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2"

    // KotlinX Serialization
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:0.8.0"

}


task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.customConfig
    into "$project.rootDir/build/outputs/"
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: "kotlinx-serialization"

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.my.mysdk-android'
            artifactId 'mysdk-android'
            version '1.0.0'
            artifact("$projectDir/build/outputs/aar/MySDK-release.aar")
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/......'
            credentials {
                username "MySDK.Android"
                password accessToken
            }
        }
    }
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of researching i finally fix the problem. So the problem was your implementations. When you publishing the library, the 3rd party implementations are not packaging. You have to tell the maven that this library is using some 3rd party libraries. If you are using build gradle kts add the below code to you publications.

```kotlin
publishing {
    publications {
        register<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            groupId = "yourGroupId"
            artifactId = "yourArtifactId"
            version = "versionOfTheLibrary"

            // You don't have to change this line. artifact("$projectDir/build/outputs/aar/MySDK-release.aar") is fine
            afterEvaluate { artifact(tasks.getByName("bundleReleaseAar")) }

            // Here is the magic happens
            pom.withXml {
                val dependencies = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")

                val addNode = { groupId: String, artifactId: String, version: String ->
                    val dependency = dependencies.appendNode("dependency")
                    dependency.appendNode("groupId", groupId)
                    dependency.appendNode("artifactId", artifactId)
                    dependency.appendNode("version", version)
                }

                addNode("com.example", "dependency name", "version")

                // In your case, add below lines
                addNode("com.squareup.retrofit2", "retrofit2", "2.9.0")
                addNode("com.squareup.okhttp3", "logging-interceptor", "4.9.1")
                addNode("com.orhanobut", "logger", "2.2.0")
                addNode("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-coroutines-android", "1.5.2")
                addNode("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-coroutines-core", "1.5.2")
                addNode("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-serialization-json", "1.3.2")
                addNode("com.jakewharton.retrofit", "retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter", "0.8.0")
               // Add other dependencies that you use in the code
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri(localProperties.getProperty("ABTOOL_MAVEN_WRITE_URL"))
            credentials {
                username = localProperties.getProperty("ABTOOL_MAVEN_USERNAME")
                password = localProperties.getProperty("ABTOOL_MAVEN_WRITE_PASSWORD")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using groovy instead of gradle.kts you can add like this

```kotlin
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.my.mysdk-android'
            artifactId 'mysdk-android'
            version '1.0.0'
            artifact("$projectDir/build/outputs/aar/MySDK-release.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")

                def addDependency = { groupId, artifactId, version ->
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode("dependency")
                    dependency.appendNode("groupId", groupId)
                    dependency.appendNode("artifactId", artifactId)
                    dependency.appendNode("version", version)
                }

                addDependency("com.example", "dependency name", "version")

                // In your case, add below lines
                addDependency("com.squareup.retrofit2", "retrofit2", "2.9.0")
                addDependency("com.squareup.okhttp3", "logging-interceptor", "4.9.1")
                addDependency("com.orhanobut", "logger", "2.2.0")
                addDependency("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-coroutines-android", "1.5.2")
                addDependency("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-coroutines-core", "1.5.2")
                addDependency("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-serialization-json", "1.3.2")
                addDependency("com.jakewharton.retrofit", "retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter", "0.8.0")
                // Add other dependencies that you use in the code
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/......'
            credentials {
                username "MySDK.Android"
                password accessToken
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what we need to do if using local aar file still not able to added third part library please suggest.